# What is the number next to your name in multiplayer?

Tags: the-last-of-us

What is the number next to your name in multiplayer ("Factions") in The Last of Us? Mine is currently at 1, and doesn't seem to be changing.

Answer (score 3):

The number next to your name is the number of weeks your clan has survived. The symbol is an indicator of how many complete 12-week cycles you have survived.

[From EvangM, Naughty Dog developer (emphasis mine)](http://forums.naughtydog.com/t5/The-Last-of-Us-Multiplayer/Ask-a-simple-question-receive-a-simple-answer-thread/m-p/40696207#M1344):

> Hi everybody, I'm back and answering questions again! I took a much-needed weekend off, but I'll be around now each day so if you have questions, I'll do my best to respond!
>
> To answer your questions S4, there is no such thing as "levels" in TLOU MP. One of the things we wanted to move away from was the traditional progression iconography and descriptions that people use to make snap judgements on whether or not a teammate/opponent is 'good' or 'bad'. Even though it works well for a lot of games, like Uncharted 3 MP, we felt it was too static for a game like this that can vary so wildly from one match to the next.
>
> **Instead, we have a small number next to your name. It displays approximately the number of weeks you have completed of MP for your entire career, not just on one clan loop. And again, this is no indicator of skill at all, merely a "timestamp" of sorts.**

Answer (score 0):

That makes no sense that it's the number of WEEKS. it's the number of MISSIONS you've completed. I've watched it since I started, and the number goes up by one after I complete each mission.it has nothing to do with weeks survived